# Couldn't understand the output of the program

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void) 
{
  int n,u = 0;
  printf("Enter length of word ");
  scanf("%d",&n);

  char word[n*2];
  printf("Enter the String \n");
  scanf("%s", word);
  printf("string that u have entered: %s\n",word);
  int i = n - 1, j = n;
  while(i >= 0)
  {
    printf("word[i-1] %c\n",word[i]);
    word[j] = word[i];
    printf("i %d\n",i);
    printf("j %d\n",j);
    i--;
    j++;
  }
  printf("reversed word stored at the last in the same array - %s\n",word);
}
```

when we give the length 3 the output doesn't give any garbage value in output but when I give greater than 3 its starts to give garbage value in the output. (yeah I know we have to add '\0' at the end of the array to stop but for length 3 without that, it works.)

Comment: It seems like you know why your code isn't working, because you give the reason in the question. Not terminating the string is undefined behavior, and quite often undefined behavior looks like a working program. You need to increase the size of `word` by 1, and terminate your string and your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you have declared the **word** as char array and alloted the size of array. So,when you are printing via indexing of array as %c --it gives the correct result. But,at the end,when you try to print the whole 'word' char array, you used %s .  Now, what %s does is : when you indicate to a string, it stores the address of the first element and keep printing the value stored in those addresses in sequential manner untill it finds the null value. So,you better use a loop to print values stored in 'word' array using %c or you can convert your char array 'word' into string & then use %s to print values inside 'word'.